# Problem opening Collada file .dae

Tags: gazebo, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am following this tutorial in orden to simulate a .dae file created with Sketchup. Running under Ros Fuerte and Gazebo 1.8.
Im trying to paste the .dae file in /Media/models but I can´t locate it. I´ll probably need your help after solving this doubt,  hehe.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188743/problem-opening-collada-file-.dae/) by [azeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/19663/azeta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tutorial:  http://wiki.ros.org/cob_gazebo_worlds/Tutorials/Create%20your%20own%20world

---

Originally posted by [azeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/19663/azeta/) with karma: 16 on 2014-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0